# Intellij Idea 13 can't find Hierarchy Tools when programing Android apps

Tags: android, intellij-idea, hierarchy

I try to find in View/Tools windows and also the right part of Intellij,but can not find as Intellij idea12.And I really want to use the tools for my Android Apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [online documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/hierarchy-tool-window.html):

> The tool window is available only after you have [built a hierarchy](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/building-class-hierarchy.html) for the first time.

Comment: Thank you very much.And I can't use it as the hierarchy tool which android sdk provided,can I?The sdk's tools can give me the analysed view

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, please clarify.

Comment: I think the Hierarchy Tools which Intellij provided is simpler than Android Sdk's hierarchyviewer or monitor.Maybe they are not a same tool and I get confused

Comment: It's not the same, see http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/viewing-hierarchies.html.